# CSS Class name containing any number

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using a css selector to be able to target all classes that start with pl-0, pl-1, pl-2, pl3, ... `[class^="pl-"]` how ever i get a conflict with some other classes of a third part integration who use elements with a class name `pl-header` :/

is there a way to use something like `[class^="pl-[0-9]"]` ?? if not, how can I apply this class `[class^="pl-"]` except when it's the child of specific div name?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `div:not(.foo) [class^="pl-"]` should work for applying it unless it's a child of .foo

Comment: thanks @rlemon :) i'll try it out and will let you know :) so i guess it's not possible using the [0-9] ??

Comment: i tried your solution but it doesn't work. using a class `.pl-header` which is a child of `div.foo` is still applied :/

Comment: [seems to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/79cnr32m/)

Comment: hmm, i'll try it again and will let you know, for sure i must have missed something!!

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
[class^="pl-"] {
   /* apply your rules */
   prop1: value1;
   prop2: value2;
}

[class^="pl-header"] {
   /* reset only for these */
   prop1: unset;
   prop2: unset;
}
```

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)

Comment: I already thought about this but the problem is that they could be many other class names (pl-header, pl-title, ....) so not sure it's a good idea to list all of them :D

Answer (score 0):

There's *three* different solutions to your problems:

1. Combine the `[class^="pl-"]` selector with the [**`:not`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class: `[class^="pl-"]:not(.pl-header)`.
2. Make use of the [**child combinator (`>`)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) to target elements that are **not** the direct child of a specific ID: `div:not(#some-id) > [class^="pl-"]`
3. Make use of [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) by applying your rules to **all** classes that start with `.pl`, and **also** applying the **default** rules specifically to `.pl-header`. If your `.pl-header` rule is more specific than your `[class^="pl-"]` selector, it will have the default rules applied, thus having the same effect as your selector only targeting the other classes.

Personally I would opt for solution one, though feel free to choose whichver suits your needs best :)

Comment: thanks for your solutions, i'll try everything tomorrow and will let you know :)

Comment: i tried #1 can't work for me because there is not only 1 selector which is `.pl-header` there are plenty of them. it's better to exclude with a parent element just like rlemon suggested but it didn't work! #2 wont work neither because of the direct child. #3 that's the solution i had in mind but too long and complicated to maintain!!

Answer (score 0):

Just spell it out. It's not that much to write:

```css
div[class^="pl-0"],
div[class^="pl-1"],
div[class^="pl-2"],
div[class^="pl-3"],
div[class^="pl-4"],
div[class^="pl-5"],
div[class^="pl-6"],
div[class^="pl-7"],
div[class^="pl-8"],
div[class^="pl-9"] {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pl-0"></div>
<div class="pl-header"></div>
<div class="pl-1"></div>
<div class="pl-footer"></div>
<div class="pl-2"></div>
<div class="pl-test"></div>
<div class="pl-55"></div>
<div class="pl-99"></div>
<div class="pl-test"></div>
<div class="pl-888"></div>
```

Comment: haha, it's the lazy way but it's actually way more complicated, here are all the classes i'm using: `[class^="px-"], [class*=" px-"], [class^="pr-"], [class*=" pr-"], [class^="pl-"], [class*=" pl-"]` so i can't write all the combinations :)

Comment: Ah, that wasn't in your question. Still, it's 10 selectors for each variation. 60 selectors totals for a complete solution. May be your best bet. (And not sure it's the "lazy way". Seems a bit labor intensive.)

Comment: hmm, i'll go for the :not() selector and see what it'll do :) but thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: haha, since i have the conflict only with pl-* I ended up writing down all the combinations for the class .pl-[0-9] :)